How do I make it possible for the user to dismiss a numerical keyboard in SwiftUI?
I have a TextField with numerical input:
TextField("Amount", text: amountRaw).keyboardType(.numberPad)

The only way I see how to dismiss this field is to move focus into a non-numeric field and then hit enter on that field. This is not ideal.
Isn't there a way to enable a dismiss keyboard button or something?
I've found people suggesting solutions like implementing click-outside to dismiss keyboard, but that's not really what I want since I want click into other text fields to work.

Putting together the answer from @rob-mayoff, @user24018863, and https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-dismiss-the-keyboard-for-a-textfield I got a good solution:
.scrollDismissesKeyboard(.interactively)

On the containing view, this is nice to have. And then:
TextField("money", value: $saveTarget, formatter: NumberFormatter())
.keyboardType(.numberPad)
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
        Spacer()
        Button("Done") {
        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
        }
        .fontWeight(.bold)
    }
}

note that the .toolbar modification needs to be made on the top level view. If applied to many fields (like in a ForEach) you will get the toolbar button multiple times.

Make sure your text field is inside a ScrollView or a Form or a List, and adorn that container with .scrollDismissesKeyboard(.interactively). This allows a swipe or drag downward to dismiss the keyboard.

Hmm... that's not amazing, but it's better than what I have I guess.

Actually in practice this feels a lot better than I expected. Thanks!

You can use focused state (in this case "@FocusState var isFocused: Bool") and toggle it with "Done" Button, done button can be added as ToolbarItem:
.keyboardType(.decimalPad)
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
        Spacer()
        Button("Done") {
            isFocused = false
        }
        .fontWeight(.bold)
    }
}

and you will get something like this
Image

Thanks! It's not quite right as it doesn't scale up cleanly, but the toolbar thing was the last key to the puzzle.

This does not work in case you have more than 1 text field

You can use the power of @FocusState
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    enum FocusedField {
            case amount, name
        }
    
    @State private var amountRaw = ""
    @State private var name = ""
    @FocusState private var focusedField: FocusedField?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Amount", text: $amountRaw)
                .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                .focused($focusedField, equals: .name)
            
            TextField("Name", text: $name)
                .focused($focusedField, equals: .name)
        }
        .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
        .padding()
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}



That's not at all what I asked.
